# cocoa NSMenu add NSMenuItem in position

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I'm trying to create an NSMenu in my application. I succesfully create the menu, with some fixed items, and now I have to add some items programmatically. I succeed also in that, but it adds the item at the bottom of the others. There's a way to put this programmatically created items between fixed items? Here's my code:

.h:

```
@interface AppController : NSObject {

    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}
```

.m

```
  [statusMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];

    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];

    NSImage *statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Icon.icns"];
    [statusItem setImage:statusImage];
    [statusItem setTitle:@"Multibox"];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Carlo | 0000000000" 
                                                  action:@selector(fooClicked:) keyEquivalent:@""]; 
    [item setTarget:self];
    [statusMenu addItem:item];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `insertItem:atIndex:` family of methods rather than the `addItem:` ones.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was searching